# How do I stack two divs onto eachoter in html?

Tags: html, css

Apparently a lot of people ask this question but it still doesn't work the closest I can get to what I want is the image I linked. I want my image in every section to go from left to right like it already is but the the second image (the right one) and it's text (the lower one) aren't going under the first 'block'. I also would like to add a third section with an image to the left again but I don't even know how to do the second one correctly.

[This is an image of the current site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvk49.png)

This is my current code of html:

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="floated-img">
            <img src="image" alt="">
            <p>
                Lorem...
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container1">
        <div id="floated-img1">
            <img src="image" alt="">
            <p>
                Lorem... 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my code of CSS:

```
#floated-img img {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -16px;
    margin-left: -16px;
}

#floated-img p {
    margin-top: -7px;
}

#floated-img1 img {
    width: 200px;
    float: right`
    margin-right: -16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an element is floated, it is taken out of the normal document flow, allowing other content to flow around it.

Now if you want your elements to be on top of each other in two rows you could wrap them in a `div` or give them some `height` :

```css
#floated-img img {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
  height:200px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -16px;
    margin-left: -16px;
  
}

#floated-img p {
    margin-top: -7px;
}

#floated-img1 img {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -16px;
    height:200px;

}
.main{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
   <div id="container">
        <div id="floated-img">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1571988840298-3b5301d5109b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" alt="">
            <p>
                Lorem... 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container1">
        <div id="floated-img1">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1571988840298-3b5301d5109b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" alt="">
            <p>
                Lorem... 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```